# Kaltura seek and playFrom in video not working with html5 player

Tags: html, video, kaltura

I can get the flash player to seek or startFrom a particular time for the video but NOT with the HTML5 player?? Am I'm missing something? I've tried lots of things!

It's not working on all this commands:

```
'mediaProxy.mediaPlayFrom' : 30
kdp.setKDPAttribute('mediaProxy','mediaPlayFrom', 30 );
kdp.sendNotification("doSeek", timesec);
```

Comment: what version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are using older version of HTML5, you need to download at least 1.7+ versions. Also you have to put it under the path of http://youKalturaServer.example.com/html5/html5lib/.

Then you need to edit your localSettings.php file to point your kaltura server url. Then change this version by default version in congig file. (/opt/kaltura/app/alpha/config).

This would solve your thing. Hope it helps.